# Wordpress Gutenberg React – render variable with HTML

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have this code in a custom WordPress Gutenberg block

```
let whole      = Math.floor(stars_client);    
let fraction   = stars_client - whole;
let stars_data = '';

for (var i = 0; i < whole; i ++) {
    stars_data = stars_data + '<i className="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
}

if (fraction > 0) {
    stars_data = stars_data + '<i class="fa fa-star-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
}

return (
    <div className="testimonial-container type_class_3">
        <div className="testimonial-image" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imagelinks})` }}></div>
        <div className="testimonial_title">{ testimonial_title }</div>
        <div className="testimmonials_starts">{ stars_data }</div>
        <div className="testimonial-text">{ testimonial_text }</div> 
        <div className="testimonial-author-line"><span className="testimonial-author">{ client_name }</span>, { title_client }</div>
    </div>
);
```

In `stars_data` variable I have a generated HTML code that I want to show. Currently the variable is not rendered as HTML. How can I render/display `stars_data` as HTML code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is being interpretd as plain text and not as an `{__html: ''}` object. To be able to interpret the HTML code like you need you have to use **[dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)** which makes use of `__html`:

```
<div className="testimmonials_starts" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: stars_data}} />
```

***NOTE:***

> **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** is React’s replacement for using **innerHTML** in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set **HTML** directly from React, but you have to type out **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** and pass an object with a **__html** key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

And your final code should look something like this:

```
let whole      = Math.floor(stars_client);    
let fraction   = stars_client - whole;
let stars_data = '';

for (var i = 0; i < whole; i ++) {
    stars_data = stars_data + '<i className="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
}

if (fraction > 0) {
    stars_data = stars_data + '<i class="fa fa-star-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
}

return (
    <div className="testimonial-container type_class_3">
        <div className="testimonial-image" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imagelinks})` }}></div>
        <div className="testimonial_title">{ testimonial_title }</div>
        <div className="testimmonials_starts" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: stars_data}} />
        <div className="testimonial-text">{ testimonial_text }</div> 
        <div className="testimonial-author-line"><span className="testimonial-author">{ client_name }</span>, { title_client }</div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you for help and explanations